# Joining tables based on values from other tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following tables. I want to run a query but I think my beginner tsql level won't help here.. It probably also is a situation where I have a bad database design.

[image: tables]

Basically I need to select all fields from `tblPhotoGalleries`. Also I need to create a seperate field named `GalleryCategoryName`.

`GalleryCategoryName` field will be the `pCatName` in `tblPhotoGalleryCats`.

If `pCatName` in `tblPhotoGalleryCats = '0'`, then that would mean, `ConnectedNewsCatID` is something other than 0. In that case;

`GalleryCategoryName` will be the CategoryName field from `tblNewsCategories` where `CategoryID = ConnectedNewsCatID`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Just want to point out naming conventions inconsistencies ; some fields are spelled out, like CategoryID where others are abbreviated like pCatID. Same goes for tables. It's my personal preference, but I prefer nice and spelled out names; it's much easier to read and work with...

Comment: I do agree with you @Dmitriy. When the whole thing is not planned befre the project starts, and you give the db tasks to designers, thats what happens!

Comment: tblPhotoGalleryCats? Do you work for [icanhascheezburger.com/](http://icanhascheezburger.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a left join on the news category table, and use a case expression to choose between the names:

```
select
  g.pgID, g.gName,
  GalleryCategoryName = case c.pCatName when '0' then n.CategoryName else c.pCatName end
from tblPhotoGalleries g
inner join tblPhotoGFalleryCats c on c.pCatID = g.FK_pCatID
left join tblNewsCategories n on n.CategoryOd = c.ConnectedNewsCatID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try starting here:

```
select *,
  case when PGC.pCatName = '0' then NC.CategoryName else PGC.pCatName end as [CatName]
  from tblPhotoGalleries as PG inner join
    tblPhotoGalleryCats as PGC on PGC.pCatID = FK_pCatID left outer join
    tblNewsCategories as NC on NC.CategoryId = ConnectedNewsCatID
```